# CreateDirectory function doesn't work at C:\Program Files

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I am trying to create a directory using CreateDirectory function at C:\Program Files in the development driver. But it doesn't seem to work as i expect. What's wrong with my function?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t *path = L"C:\\Program Files\\log";
    CreateDirectory ( path , NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that back-slashes are special inside string literals, and that you need to escape them with their own back-slash \\.

Comment: Like this `"C:\\Program Files\\log";` or this `"C:/Program Files/log";`.

Comment: And your process must be running elevated to create a directory in Program Files.

Comment: Always check `GetLastError()` after such a call, it will give some clues.

Comment: In C++ (and C), the backslash is special in string and character literals, and used to escape the following character.   To gets single backslashes you need to use two.   For example `L"C:\\Program Files\\log"`.    Alternatively, windows API functions respond to forward slashes too, such as `L"C:/Program Files/log"`.

Comment: I change *path = L"C:\\Program Files\\log" , but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you try running your process as adminstrator, most probably it does not have sufficient priviledges to create the folder.

Comment: You can also use a character string literal if you don't like escaping. `const wchar_t* str = LR"(C:\Program Files\log)"`. On another note, why does this say `driver`? Are you actually trying to develop a `Windows` driver?

Comment: YES, i am developing a windows driver and want to write a log file in C: \ Program Files \ log

Comment: A driver is a module in kernel space that has privileged access to the system. Typically a driver uses the system event log. See [logging errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/logging-errors).

Answer (score 1):

"I want to write a log file in C:\Program Files\log"

That's not the correct location. Back in the Windows 2000 era, that would be a style comment, but nowadays that is a security error. If you'd call `GetLastError`, you's see it returns 5 (Access Denied).

You talk about "development driver". I don't know what you mean by that. It could be that you're talking about real drivers, in which case the answer would be complex. But if you're writing drivers, then you'd be used to complex answers, and you wouldn't be stumped by this. So I'm assuming that you're just writing a program. In that case, there's `FOLDERID_ProgramData` (Likely `c:\ProgramData`, but call `SHGetKnownFolderPath`)

Comment: Any user can create files and directories in ProgramData, and the creator will be granted full control. A program should create a subdirectory for its data, and preferrably create a hierarchical tree starting with the organization name (e.g. "%ProgramData%\Contoso\Driver\log"). By default users have read and execute access to files and directories in ProgramData, but a program has to set custom security if users need write/append or delete access to files and directories created by others. If needed, custom security should be set on creation, since the creator has full control.